# Assigning to cllocationdegrees ('aka double') from incompatible type id_nullable

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

```
NSString* lat,*longi; 
lat= [[deliveryInfo objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"latitude"];

NSLog(@"LATITUDE %@",lat); longi= [[deliveryInfo objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"longitude"]; 

c.latitude=[[deliveryInfo objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"latitude"]; 

c.longitude=-74.0565298; sp.latitudeDelta=0.01f; sp.longitudeDelta=0.01f; 

re.center=c; re.span=sp; mapView.region=re; MKPointAnnotation *p=[[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init]; 

p.coordinate=c; [p setTitle:@"USA"]; 

[p setSubtitle:@"Location"]; [mapView addAnnotation:p];
```

Comment: have u tried     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f",c.latitude] = [[deliveryInfo objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"latitude"]

Comment: MKCoordinateRegion re;
    MKCoordinateSpan sp;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D c;

Comment: could u post ur complete method code

Comment: NSString* lat,*longi;
       lat= [[deliveryInfo objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"latitude"];
        NSLog(@"LATITUDE %@",lat);
    longi= [[deliveryInfo objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"longitude"];
    c.latitude=[[deliveryInfo objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"latitude"];
    c.longitude=-74.0565298;
    sp.latitudeDelta=0.01f;
    sp.longitudeDelta=0.01f;
    re.center=c;
    re.span=sp;
    mapView.region=re;
       MKPointAnnotation *p=[[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
    p.coordinate=c;
    [p setTitle:@"USA"];
    [p setSubtitle:@"Location"];
    [mapView addAnnotation:p];

Comment: where have u declared c.latitude , longtitude , show me declaration

Comment: @Imran I approved your edit. If you're going to edit code from comments into posts, it's best to say so in the Edit Summary. E.g. "Added code from OP's comment". Otherwise, it may look like you're hijacking the question. On the review page, we don't see the comments, only the edit suggestion.

Comment: MKCoordinateRegion re;
    MKCoordinateSpan sp;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D c;

Comment: Hi IMran, 

Any more information you required?

Comment: cant understand by ur code buddy

Comment: @lj999 please always edit your question rather than adding any code in comments, and explain both what you're trying to do and which line in the code causes the problem.

Comment: In this code when iam trying to add coordinates from webservice its showing the error. particularly in this step.
 c.latitude=[[deliveryInfo objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"latitude"];

Comment: thanks for the support. I have resolved the issue by adding float value with cordinates like this:

 c.latitude=[[[deliveryInfo objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue];
    c.longitude=[[[deliveryInfo objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"longitude"] floatValue];

Comment: @lj999 ur problem got resolved na, please update it in answer. it would be good for others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
c.latitude=[[[deliveryInfo objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue]; c.longitude=[[[deliveryInfo objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"longitude"]floatValue]; 
 sp.latitudeDelta=0.01f;
    sp.longitudeDelta=0.01f;
    re.center=c;
    re.span=sp;
    mapView.region=re;
```